# DC Adapter on AC Adapter Speaker

Tags: power-supply, voltage, ac, dc, ac-dc

i've Speaker with woofer requiring AC 12 voltage, and i have DC 12 voltage Adapter. 
However, speakers are working properly.

but Can i use DC 12 V Adapther with the Speaker which is requiring AC 12 voltage, without any future damage ?

Comment: Your question is so garbled that it is difficult to tell what you are asking.  Apparently your speaker device requires 12 VAC power and it first appears you are asking whether it will work on 12 VDC power instead.  But then you say they are working properly, so that question doesn't make sense.

Comment: i'm saying that the speakers are working properly now, but will they work without any damage ?

Comment: @BhaveshGangani - when it comes to guarantees, your guarantee is technically invalidated so legally nobody can say it will work without any damage and it would be foolish of anyone to say it would without detailed analysis. However, I suspect the item's cost isn't worth worrying about this sort of thing so continue using it but don't expect to run it flat-out without problems.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is an important difference between AC and DC.

AC is Alternating Current, which means that the poles of the voltage source will switch continously at 50 or 60Hz, depending on your geographical location. This looks like this:

However, DC is Direct Current, which means that the poles of the voltage source will not switch: one is the positive and one the negative, and that doesn't change. A diagram:

[image]

<sup>Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_current</sup>

When your device expects an AC voltage, it's most likely that will be transformed to another voltage, for what it needs AC, *or* he just needs AC for something else. In either case, DC won't work and might harm your device!

Comment: Quite agree - and there's also the question of current rating as well. Stick to the correct adapter for the job. (+1)

Comment: see my edited question.

Comment: @BhaveshGangani answer stays the same: you shouldn't use a DC adapter for an AC device.

Answer (score 2):

The OP says the 12VDC adapter is "working properly" and I had a suspicion it would work although probably not 100% properly. He's using it to provide power to a woofer speaker and without doubt, if the spec says 12VAC, this voltage would be converted to DC at some point in the woofer system.

I would also speculate that it is unlikely that there would be a conventional transformer inside the woofer amplifier that would need AC power in order to produce a different AC voltage - this would not make sense because cost would dictate that the woofer amplifier takes the AC power direct and converts to DC.

Simplest way to convert to DC is of course a rectifier and smoothing capacitor and this will also allow DC through without any issues. So I am speculating that a modern woofer with inbuilt amplifier would probably work from DC BUT with certain limitations.

The limitations are to do with the DC that is obtainable from 12VAC - it's likely that the internal DC voltage after the rectifier will be about 15.5VDC and this is higher than you would obtain from a 12V dc supply (it would yield about 10.5Vdc).

This means that for normal listening levels the woofer amplifier will produce sound levels from the speaker with little distortion BUT when called to produce bigger sounds distortion will creep in much earlier because the power rails are not high enough to do the job.

*I'm certainly not recommending that my answer be taken as a statement that this will always work....*

It won't always work but, on a system like this, there is a reasonable probability it will work adequately but not to full spec. There is also no excuse for not using the proper PSU adapter BUT if I was faced with this scenario I'd probably pop the lid off the equipment and check to see that there is a bridge rectifier on the power input to the amplifier and that would be enough to confirm it will work.